# Clearing caches of libs during tests and moving to ESM from common.js

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, es6-modules, commonjs

Issue: https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push/issues/772 (look at last 2 comments) 
File in question: https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push/blob/master/test/testSendNotification.js

I am having problem with rewriting library to use ESM. The way author was clearing state before each test is a bit puzzling to me.

```js
  mocha.beforeEach(function() {
    requestBody = null;
    requestDetails = null;

    // Delete caches of web push libs to start clean between test runs
    delete require.cache[path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'index.js')];
    delete require.cache[path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'web-push-lib.js')];
```

I never encountered cleaning state in test by deleting& importing libs, can I easily rework it into ESM or is this approach not gonna work? Additionaly is this really normal approach to problem like this or is it some hack?

There seems to be no way to delete imported state in ESM which is by the way something I never even thought of in other languages. I don't want to rewrite whole test approach since I am just trying to fix simple issue for lib

Comment: "*is this really normal approach to problem like this or is it some hack?*" - it's more like a hack. It forces nodejs to re-evaluate the module, thereby re-initialising module-scoped variables. A cleaner way would be for the module itself to export a `resetCache()` function.